# Animating the Bosonic String

Tags: classical-mechanics, string-theory, simulations

I am interested in studying the classical solutions to the Bosonic string in flat 3+1 dim. spacetime by having them rendered a moving picture on a computer.  This is partly for fun, and partly to develop an intuition for their kinematical behavior.

But, I'm not sure where/how to start.

Should I start from the **Nambu-Goto Action** or the **Polyakov Action**?  And, should I use the **light-cone** gauge or the **covariant** gauge?  Of course, whatever my choice, I should get the same results, but I want to know the choice that is *most convenient to obtain solutions that can be visualized*.

Finally, what interesting **initial-values** should I use?  I would like to investigate the motion of the string doing all sorts things.  Any suggestions here?

Eventually I hope to animate the classical scattering of two strings, if possible (I'm not too sure if classical strings interact...).